# How to check prop types of an arbitrary react element variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there a way to check the prop types of a react element variable? For example, if I have the following code:

`let component = <MyComponent />;`

I can get the props by doing this:

`component.type.propTypes; // e.g. => { prop1 : f (), prop2 : f() };`

But how can I check the types of those props? In the context, the `<MyComponent />` variable has the potential to be one of any number of different components, and I need a list of the props and propTypes accordingly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like Flow or Typescript if you want true type checking in javascript.

Because Proptypes are not enforceable, it is really hard to rely on them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I definitely have heard that before and need to start using one of those. However, I'm not sure if that would solve my problem here. A little more context: I'm building a for fun 'react playground' in which you can choose a component, and then manipulate the props in real time and see how the component works. Consequently, the sidebar in which you manipulate the props needs to know a) what props the selected component is expecting, and b) what type each prop is. Not sure if that extra context helps, but do you have any ideas on how to address that second point?